# Shell script syntax warning about missing quote

Tags: shell, syntax

I'm a new beginner of shell scripting. I cannot figure out why the following script keep pop up warning that there are some missing 「"」? Can someone help me take a look?

```
  if [ $portalweb_prepared == "true"];then
    CHECK="false";
  elif [ $ims_prepared == "true"] &&[ $same_version == "false" ];then
    CHECK="false";
  elif [ $portalapi_prepared == "true"] &&[ $same_version == "false" ];then
    CHECK="false";
  fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be written as follows:

```
if [ "$portalweb_prepared" = "true" ]
then
    CHECK="false"
elif [ "$ims_prepared" = "true" ] && [ "$same_version" = "false" ]
then
    CHECK="false"
elif [ "$portalapi_prepared" = "true" ] && [ "$same_version" = "false" ]
then
    CHECK="false"
fi
```

Very similar, but almost all the spaces are significant, and the rest aid readability.

Comment: I think the spaces around the double ampersands are not significant.

Comment: What is really important are the spaces around the `[` and `]` in IFs statements! And I agree with spaces around &&.

Comment: It's truly works!!!  So, the space really affects in shell script syntax?

Comment: Yeah, Bash is a weird language like that.